# How to run C# app with Entities Data Model Independently

Tags: c#

I'm Using Entities Data Model, from C#, I want to run my app independently(separately from my source code), what things that should I copy to a folder?

[image: Current Situation in my new Folder]

Answer (score 0):

I just tried move my Database to the folder, and it can run properly. But i have new problems, how to settings the EF path and My Database's path, I know I can set it with the ConnectionString. But I dont know how to make a proper ConnectionString that can work Dynamically depends on the Application is to be.